# How to monitor in real time all the Python files that are running on the computer including files started from subprocess?

Tags: python

I have 4 Python files that are executed separately and uninterruptedly on my computer throughout the day via cmd. Within the codes, there are `subprocess` that execute other Python files in the background.

To keep track of which files are currently being executed, I added a function to the code of all of them that, when the file starts executing, creates an empty `.txt` file in a specific folder and deletes this file when it finishes executing.

For example, the `subprocess` executes the file `collect_data.py`, so this file at the beginning of the code creates the file `collect_data.txt`, does its work, and when finished, deletes the file `collect_data.txt`.

Note: The 4 main files that run all day also create their own `.txt` and delete it when they stop running.

[image]

As the files complete their service, they are deleted and only the main ones that are still running remain:

[image]

I monitor the existing files in the aforementioned folder using `watchdog`:

```python
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import tkinter as tk
import os

class FileChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, file_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_list = file_list

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        self.update_file_list()

    def update_file_list(self):
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)
        self.file_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        for file in files:
            self.file_list.insert(tk.END, file)

def monitor_folder():
    event_handler.update_file_list()
    root.after(1000, monitor_folder)

folder_path = r"C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\utilities_code\run_process"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Lista de Arquivos")
root.minsize(400, 300)
file_list = tk.Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="white")
file_list.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

event_handler = FileChangeHandler(file_list)
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_path)
observer.start()

monitor_folder()
root.mainloop()
```

What I do, I know that it is a palliative form and I would like to know if there is any intelligent and correct method to specifically address my need to be completely and absolutely sure of which files are being executed and also to track a possible file that not able to complete its execution leaving your process open "forever"?